# Do Roche limits apply to Kerr ring black holes?

Tags: amateur-observing, roche-limit

I was wondering if a smaller black hole orbiting a larger one  could be torn apart by the Roche limit or tidal force or other, if the center of the blackhole was not a singularity but a Kerr ring of Neutrons?

Comment: Although that question is not explictly about rotating black holes, I think the answer is the same:

Comment: BTW, we don't know exactly what happens at the centre of a Schwarzschild BH or the ring of a Kerr BH, we need a Quantum Gravity theory for that. However, we don't expect normal matter to be able to survive there, even something as small as a neutron will be disrupted by the tidal force. Also, in pure (non-quantum) General Relativity a BH singularity is never in the past light cone of any observer, even an observer inside the event horizon. That is, the singularity only exists in your future, not your past, until you get there.